# Cannot connect to mongo db database, showing timeout error

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have created a react app, and I have connected the mongoDB database, now the problem is whenever I start the node server the server gets started as well as the mongodb database, but most of the time the mongoDB database shows timeout error.

I am adding image, have a look through it [image: Qerytxt etimeout error]for the error as well as I am showing my pacakage.json file.

```
 {
  "name": "ewk",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "abcd",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node backend/server",
    "server": "nodemon backend/server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix frontend",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "data:import": "node backend/seeder",
    "data:destroy": "node backend/seeder -d"
  },
  "author": "xyz",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.1.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

This is my database configuration code:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const connectDB = async () => {
    try{
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true
        })

        console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`)
    } catch (error){
            console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`)
            process.exit(1)
    }
}

export default connectDB
```

I have added the uri which I added in env file:

```
mongodb+srv://abj:*******@ewfsa-cluster.hbwdr.mongodb.net/EWFSA?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Comment: It seems your proxy is causing an issue, instead of using localhost try using http://127.0.0.1. can you add you route code and proxy code too?

Comment: Where should I use 12.0.0.1 ?

Comment: It is showing me that your are using proxy in your error logs. You can use localhost instead of IP address and vice versa. I need to see how you have created your proxy.

Comment: If you are doing it locally you only need to use localhost. Please, show us the file where you are connecting to mongodb.

Comment: I haven't created proxy

Comment: I have updated some code now

Comment: If you check the logs, you can see the error "could not proxy request /api/product from localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1:5000", which is refusing the connection.

Comment: I have update the code (added uri) please check